# Monacaデバッガーの機能について

Tags: monaca

調べたんですけど調べ方が悪いのか出てこなくて
Monacaデバッガーでiosのアプリをステップ実行したいのですが、できますでしょうか。

Androidのほうは下の記事でやれることがわかっているのですが
http://blog.asial.co.jp/1333

大変申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

カスタムビルド版デバッガーが必要ですが、iOS版もsafariを用いたUSBデバッグが可能みたいです。下記の記事をお読みください。
http://docs.monaca.mobi/ja/manual/debugger/debug/#monaca-debugger-with-usb-debugging

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。